# Best way to run many processes in background

Tags: android, performance, service, broadcastreceiver, multiprocessing

I have to implement something that let me run simultaneously many processes in background. The problem is I don't know how many of those from the beginning and all of them have to be processed in the same way but with different parameters. I'm wondering what's the best ways to implement it both as efficiency and as low battery cost. Any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: Use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Its not as simple as just using a Service - which will still run on the main (UI) thread. Depending on your requirements, you need to spawn threads inside your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the answers that suggest a `Service` - depending on your requirements, you need to consider that the `Service` code will be run on the main application thread, just like code inside an `Activity`.

[Excerpt from the Service page in the Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you
>   will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and
>   the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.

What this means is that its not the same as running a background thread.

If you need true background processing, you should consider running each of your processes in a background thread that is started by the `Service`.

The `Service` allows you to run when your app is not in the foreground. The multiple threads allow it to run off the main UI thread.

---

In terms of managing these multiple threads, consider the use of something like the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Full description of every aspect of that is out of scope for this question, but I believe you will learn a lot by reading the Developer Guide link. They provide a lot of detail plus some demo code.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody for your answers. I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll check it out.

Comment: Good luck. Start by moving some code into a `Service`, so your activities can be moved to background. Only start work on the threads once you have a stable grasp of the service model. There are a few tricks, but it becomes quite simple after a few attempts.